# DbTransaction Attempts PrepareCommand and cannot find DbConnection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0

I'm receiving the following error when I enact a specific function in my code that runs a ton of other database calls with transaction.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connection
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.PrepareCommand(DbCommand command, DbConnection connection)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.PrepareCommand(DbCommand command, DbTransaction transaction)
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command, DbTransaction transaction)
at net.cadat.dataManager.dbConn.DataAccess.execute(String storedProcedure, StoredProcedureParameter[] sqlParameters)
```

Although it would be difficult to post my whole source code, basically the flow of database calls are like this:

```
_db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
_conn = _db.CreateConnection();
_conn.Open();
if (_transaction == null)
  _transaction = _conn.BeginTransaction();
// later in code
_command = _db.GetStoredProcCommand(storedProcedure);
DataSet ds = null;
if (_transaction == null)
  ds = _db.ExecuteDataSet(_command);
else
  ds = _db.ExecuteDataSet(_command, _transaction);
```

Obviously the above code spans in different functions of a databasefactory class. I call it "DA" class. So the DA class gets passed around in each function BY value, and it seems like when DA gets passed around, transactions or connections are disappearing?!?!

Recently I made sure the build is .Net 4.0 framework targeted, because before it was 2.0, and I realized 2.0 has a bug regarding the connection parameter disappearing with GC.

yet it is still happening. The connection parameter is disappearing when it gets passed around. The error happens when the first database call happens in that particular function, and before the commit of the transaction.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by it passed around? when you pass as arguments to another method? Also is your "`DA`" a local variable or class level variable?

Comment: It's a local variable. I pass DA to other sub-functions. Somehow because I'm using transactions, passing it around, is causing problems. If I disable transactions, everything works fine.

Comment: It is also passed by value. This is not something I would ever do in C++, but I am really confused with how C# allows this (and the previous coders also did this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In entlib, you are not supposed to create a connection.
Try this:

```
_db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    _command = _db.GetStoredProcCommand(storedProcedure);
    DataSet ds = _db.ExecuteDataSet(_command);

    ts.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Why not btw (curiosity, is it because entlib manages that already, so what happens when I do?)? Can you explain why you use "using (", what does the using do that simply excluding it won't do?

Comment: I mean, I know it is an IDisposable but, at the end of the code I do have a finally { dispose } for the connection and the transaction if not null.

Comment: Hmm, now that I removed a ton of if(connection==null)createconnection(); type stuff, the code seems to be working better, why is this? How was this code working before then?

Comment: I don't know what happens internally when you create a connection manually. All I know is you're not supposed to do that (except during special cases?). The using statement is just a shortcut of try finally { dispose }.